# LyX on MacOS two different files yet connected?

Tags: lyx, mac, links

###### Disclaimer

I’m not sure how to even phrase the issue here. So if you find a better way, please comment it I’ll edit the question.

I don’t know either if it’s a LyX or macOS related question. So please, point me towards the right direction.

##### The question

On a macOS computer, I was editing `newfile.lyx` in `folder1/`. Then, to organize, I moved (drag and drop) the LyX file along with the bib file attached to it to `folder1/folder2/`.

First, it apparently didn’t just **move** the file, but rather **copied and paste** to `folder2/`, because I still have the `newfile.lyx` in `folder1/` as well as having it in `folder2/`.

Second, and most importantly, the two files are “*connected*”. By that I mean that when I modify either file (they both have the same name, just not the same path) the other gets updated with the modification made to the other file, and vice versa.

I verified if for some reason it there was a symbolic link linking the two files, but there is no link at all.

Any idea why that could be?

#### Edit

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
%Your LaTeX preamble 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,autocite=footnote,backend=biber,natbib=true,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex-chicago}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxcitenames=1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
        \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
        \bibhyperref{#1}}
\savebibmacro{cite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
        \printtext[citehyperref]{%
                \restorebibmacro{cite}%
                \usebibmacro{cite}}}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language french
\language_package default
\inputencoding utf8
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "times" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command biber
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 12
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine biblatex-natbib
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style plain
\biblatex_bibstyle chicago-notes
\biblatex_citestyle chicago-notes
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2.57cm
\topmargin 2.57cm
\rightmargin 2.57cm
\bottommargin 2.57cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style french
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header
```

Comment: If you open a lyx file with a text editor (like notepad) you can see the lyx commands that actually build what you see inside the lyx gui, including the various changes you have made in the document settings menu. My attempt would be to check if there is any "link" between the two. The lyx commands you are about to read are somewhat self explanatory. Give it a try

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I gave it a try and can’t find anything suspicious. I will add the LyX preamble to my question. If you could skim through it, maybe I missed something.